# Create full screen bottomsheets with bottomBar in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I do have a requirement in jetpack compose where I need a bottom bar in my scaffold also a bottom sheet with adjustable height. I can achieve only any one of these.
I had to sacrifice the bottom bar with below code:

```
BottomSheetScaffold(sheetContent = {//anything here})
   { innerPadding -> Box(){}
   }
```

I have no option to use bottom bar here whereas I have the freedom to adjust the height of the sheet. The second solution is using ModalBottomSheetLayout where I can add scaffold inside it and add bottom bar but won't be able to adjust the height of sheet.

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
   sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
   sheetContent = {//anything here}
){
     Scaffold(
        topBar = {
                //
        },
        bottomBar = {
                //
        },
     ){
         innerPadding -> Box(){}
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be possibly solved with BottomSheetScaffold. You can adjust its height in closed position via `sheetPeekHeight`. To have a bottombar element when the bottom sheet is collapsed, you should read this article and take a look at the related sample. The principle of this solution is to animate the contents of the bottom sheet to bottom bar when it's collapsed, and to animate to the content you want in your bottom sheet when it's opened.

[the article that explains the solution](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-animate-bottomsheet-content-using-jetpack-compose-3eab972b3bdc), and [the sample](https://github.com/egorikftp/compose-animated-bottomsheet).

If that doesn't work for you, then you should probably look at your own composable realisation. The requirements for implementing bottom sheet-like functionality are: `nestedScroll`, `swipeable` and `offset` Modifier extensions. How to deal with them you can find here: [article about nested scrolling and bottom sheets](https://www.droidcon.com/2021/11/09/how-to-master-swipeable-and-nestedscroll-modifiers-in-jetpack-compose/).